# Error installing Virtualbox Additions on Debian 9

Tags: debian, kernel, compiling, virtualbox

I am trying to install Virtualbox Guest Additions on a new Debian 9 installation and get an error when building modules. Packages `build-essential`, `module-assistant`, `dpkg`, `linux-headers-4.0.3` are installed:

```
$ sudo apt install build-essential dpkg linux-headers-4.0.3-3
$ sudo apt build-dep -y linux
```

To install the Additions I run:

```
$ sudo mount -o remount,exec,ro /media/cdrom0
$ sudo /media/cdrom0/VBoxLinuxAddons.run
```

And get the error:

```
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 5.1.6 Guest Additions for Linux...........
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Removing installed version 5.1.6 of VirtualBox Guest Additions...
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
vboxadd.sh: Building Guest Additions kernel modules.
Failed to set up service vboxadd, please check the log file
/var/log/VBoxGuestAdditions.log for details.
sergiy@debian-pc-1:~$
```

Log `/var/log/VBoxGuestAdditions.log` contains:

```
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxadd.service → /lib/systemd/system/vboxadd.service.
vboxadd.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong.
vboxadd.sh: failed: Please check that you have gcc, make, the header files for your Linux kernel and possibly perl installed..
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxadd-service.service → /lib/systemd/system/vboxadd-service.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxadd-x11.service → /lib/systemd/system/vboxadd-x11.service.
```

File `/var/log/vboxadd-install.log` contains:

```
grep: /lib/modules/4.9.0-3-amd64/build/include/linux/version.h: No such file or directory
make KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= -C /lib/modules/4.9.0-3-amd64/build SUBDIRS=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 -j1 modules
make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-3-amd64 KBUILD_SRC=/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-3-common \
-f /usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-3-common/Makefile modules
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (                \
echo >&2;                                                       \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";           \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";      \
echo >&2 ;                                                      \
/bin/false)
mkdir -p /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions/*
make -f /usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-3-common/scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0
   gcc-6 -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.VBoxGuest-linux.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include -I/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-3-common/arch/x86/
------------------------------------------------
In file included from /tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux/the-linux-kernel.h:98:0,
                 from /tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:31:
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-3-common/include/linux/mm.h:1298:6: note: declared here
 long get_user_pages_remote(struct task_struct *tsk, struct mm_struct *mm,
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-3-common/scripts/Makefile.build:298: recipe for target '/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.o' failed
make[4]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.o] Error 1
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-3-common/Makefile:1507: recipe for target '_module_/tmp/vbox.0' failed
make[3]: *** [_module_/tmp/vbox.0] Error 2
Makefile:150: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
make[2]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
/tmp/vbox.0/Makefile.include.footer:84: recipe for target 'vboxguest' failed
make: *** [vboxguest] Error 2
Creating user for the Guest Additions.
Creating udev rule for the Guest Additions kernel module.
```

Output `uname -a`:

```
Linux debian-pc-1 4.9.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u1 (2017-06-18) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

$ dpkg -l | grep virtualbox

Result of command `dpkg -l | grep virtualbox` on host Ubuntu 16.10:

```
ii  virtualbox                                  5.1.6-dfsg-2                                       amd64        x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
rc  virtualbox-5.1                              5.1.22-115126~Ubuntu~yakkety                       amd64        Oracle VM VirtualBox
ii  virtualbox-dkms                             5.1.6-dfsg-2                                       all          x86 virtualization solution - kernel module sources for dkms
ii  virtualbox-qt                               5.1.6-dfsg-2                                       amd64        x86 virtualization solution - Qt based user interface
ii  virtualbox-source                           5.1.6-dfsg-2                                       all          x86 virtualization solution - kernel module source
```

File `/etc/apt/sources.list` in Debian guest:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main contrib non-free
```

ISO with Virtualbox addons 5.1.6 was downloaded by VirtualBox from official site. What's wrong? How to fix it?

Comment: Try running with locale "C", which should return English output. Also, please include the output of `uname -a` in your question. Also, perhaps more pertinently, where did you get your VB Additions from?

Comment: I added information about VirtualBox addons and uname, thanks.

Comment: You probably don't want to mix the versions in Debian with the versions from the Virtualbox web site. In particular, the Debian packages `virtualbox-guest-additions-iso`  provides the Virtualbox Additions (not addons) that you are trying to install. Please include the output of `dpkg -l  | grep virtualbox` in your question.

Comment: command `dpkg -l | grep virtualbox` gets empty result, it is guest system, not host.

Comment: Run that command on the host, not the guest.

Comment: Did you try apt upgrade

Comment: I updated the guest system, but it didnt help.

Answer (score 5):

The `linux-headers-4.0.3-3` belong to Ubuntu . You should install the `linux-headers-4.9.0-3-amd64` package on debian 9:

```
apt install linux-headers-4.9.0-3-amd64
```

Install `dkms` and prepare the kernel to build the kernel module:

```
apt install dkms
m-a prepare
```

Run the `VBoxLinuxAddons.run`.

Comment: This one did it for me.  I'd had additions working previously but I think there had been a kernel upgrade (or possibly even the whole move to squeeze) by the time I next tried to upgrade it.  The installer's logs did include some mention it can't find the headers, but just installing/updating the linux-headers package alone didn't fix it... the dkms (and I also needed module-assistant) and m-a prepare were also needed.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar setup to the OP. I even tried what @GAD3R suggested at one point.

In the end, I found the solution to be to install the latest version of VirtualBox (5.1.24) and download the guest additions separately from `http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.24/`.

Comment: I installed newest version of Virtualbox - 5.1.26, and update addons, now it works. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: Indeed, this issue was fixed in later Additions.